# Set header to null in navigationOptions using React Navigation in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to set the `header` to `null`.

Currently, I am trying to do

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
})

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  header: null
}
```

But the above `header: null` doesn't work.

But the below code does work.

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

How do I make it work in `HomeStack.navigationOptions`?

Also, can I set a global `header: null` because I don't want `header` in any of my screens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this (note headerModel: 'none'):

```
const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Home },
  },
  { initialRouteName: 'Home', headerMode: 'none' }
);
```

Comment: That indeed works but I have to set it in 4 places anyways for 4 stack navigators. Can I set up some global `header:none`?

Comment: I think the best way is to extend `createStackNavigator` with the settings you need. Check here for more details on how to achieve this behavior: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html